# Why these two cases are not equivalent

Tags: sql-server, database, case

I have written a sql query that check is **@Collegein** not equals to 0, if so then get college_code according to that else go for all colleges.I have already used this technique but never tried it for multivalues .I have this condition in "where"

```
College_code in (CASE WHEN  @Collegein != '0' THEN  (SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@Collegein, ',')) ELSE College_code  END)
```

This works fine for **@Collegein = '1'** but fails for **@Collegein = '1,2'** , giving error subquery return more than 1 value.

While below code works fine for  **@Collegein = '1,2'**

```
College_code in (select * from dbo.Split(@Collegein ,','))
```

What could be that possible solution for this or alternative solution. One more thing why "in" not working here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot work. While `IN` clearly deals with multiple values, `CASE` can return only a single value. Therefore the subquery in your case is expected to return a single value and that's why you get the error. You have to use `OR` here:

```
@Collegein = '0'
OR
(
   @Collegein != '0'
   AND College_code IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@Collegein, ','))
)
```

Comment: I get that it saying it expecting single value but why. "in" can handle multiple values and it's fine for this one too "College_code in (select * from dbo.Split(@Collegein ,','))". Then why it expecting single value for first query. Thanks for the alternative logic but I have already tried this logic before asking the Q and it takes ages(more than 15 min) to give output. By the way thanks for the reply

Comment: `IN` _can_ handle multiple values but `CASE` can't.

Comment: I just mark this answer for the last comment, as I know your logic is also right but just last explanation make my doubt clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Collegein = '0' 
OR 
EXISTS(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@Collegein, ',') WHERE Items = College_code)
```

**Addition**(based on Thomas's answer):

```
@Collegein = '0'
OR
College_code IN(SELECT items FROM dbo.Split(@Collegein, ','))
```

Comment: Yes it helps, thanks for the alternative. @Thomas Schremser logic was also right. But will some one help me to get this that why my query was expecting for single value. Thanks, if any could make me understand that.

Comment: in my code if `@Collegein` is equal zero then not check another condition else check this and return final result as a true or false